# Spatialite intersection & transform?

Tags: spatialite

Need to reproject features (Poly & Point) to Local CRS, buffer the Poly, then clip the points based on the buffer, then reproject back to original to WGS84. Tested query without they reprojections (st_transform) functions and it worked, but unsure what is going wrong when the st_transform functions are added?

```
SELECT
    ST_TRANSFORM(ST_INTERSECTION(
        (SELECT ST_BUFFER(ST_COLLECT(ST_TRANSFORM(geom,SRID_Local)),5280) FROM Poly),
            ST_TRANSFORM(Point.geom,SRID_Local)),SRID_Original) AS geom,
FROM
    Poly,Point
WHERE
    ST_INTERSECTION(
        (SELECT ST_BUFFER(ST_COLLECT(ST_TRANSFORM(geom,SRID_Local)),5280) FROM Poly),
            ST_TRANSFORM(Point.geom,26913)) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Buffering a collection of polygons in different coordinate systems will create different new polygons. Then the set of points that intersect that buffer might be different. But the question of whether you **need** to do this re-projection or not depends on your particular situation and goals.

BTW, what's the purpose of the `WHERE` clause in your SQL expression above?